# openssl on Mac OS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I working on a web application using .net core on MacOS. When I am trying to run

```
dotnet restore
```

in terminal, it throw an error as

`log  : Restoring packages for /Users/saber/code/aspnet/WebA/project.json...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception.
error:   Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module could not be found.
error:    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

It seems like I am not linking OpenSSL correctly.

If I run: 

`brew install openssl`

I will get:

`Warning: openssl-1.0.2j already installed, it's just not linked.`

And

`$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

ln: /usr/local/lib//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib: File exists

$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

ln: /usr/local/lib//libssl.1.0.0.dylib: File exists`

Also if I run `which openssl`
,It gives me:`/usr/bin/openssl`

Any could help with this kind of situation please?